# How to unittest valid img src links in a template response

Tags: python, django, python-unittest, django-testing

I have a view that renders a template with an image:

```
<html>
...
<img src="/static/img/mypic.jpg" />
...
</html>
```

I want to write a unit test that asserts this `img src` is valid and does not return a 404 broken link.

```
def test_myimage(self):
    response = self.client.get('/static/img/mypic.jpg')
```

However, although I know this link is in fact valid, the test returns 404.

Why does this occur and how can I test valid img src links?

Comment: I don't think the test client serves static files...

Comment: That would explain it(!)

Comment: assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use Django's built-in static file tools [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/). Then you can use something like `<img src="{% static 'mypic.jpg' %}" />` and Django will take care of making sure the file exists. If you use this, then you don't need to write unit tests for static files at all.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately if you included an invalid src it would still throw and error, hence a test is needed.

Comment: With this method, you can test that the template renders with a normal unit test and see if any errors are thrown. No need to modify the test server to serve static files.

Comment: Yes, but you would have to load the page in a server. This isn't a unit test for validating an image src.